# Creating a Collector map that allows new records to be added to a related table while not allowing spatial features to be created or deleted?

Tags: relationship-class, relates, arcgis-collector

I am trying to create inspection maps for Collector that are very similar to what can be found at this link:

https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/02/18/related-tables-exploring-new-ways-to-use-collector-for-arcgis/

In order for these maps to function correctly for our needs, I need to have editing capabilities that would only allow for several attributes in a spatial layer to be edited and be able to add new inspection records to a related table (defined by a relationship class).  Except for this to work appropriately I cannot have the spatial layer so that it can have features added or deleted.

Is there a way to have this type of functionality while using Collector for ArcGIS?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what Collector designed for.
To limit editing to attributes update, go to Feature Layer Settings and set it:

[image]

To enable/disable some attributes from editing open map with Feature layer of interest go to Configure Attributes:

[image]

And check/uncheck relevant column:

[image]

Adding row to related table is no big deal either, just follow document you are refering to

**UPDATE:**

Select "Only add new features" in *What kind of editing is allowed* group. And you'll be able to add new record to related table. I just tested it.

Comment: This is basically what I have done, except I never published as a feature layer, just a feature service and when I do publish my data as feature layer the data is not always visible.  And if I have the data set to only update feature attributes I still can't seem to add new records in the related table, I can only view records that are already created.

Comment: It seems the only way that I have the ability to add new records to a table is when there is also the ability to add new features to the spatial layer (unless I disable all editing for the spatial features while in ArcGIS Online), and for the purpose of these maps I cannot have that.  But I still need to have the ability to edit the attributes in the spatial layer.

Comment: Are you doing it in AGOL or collector?

Comment: The actual data collection is happening via collector, but all of the initial set up is being done in ArcGIS Online.

Comment: See update. It is not ideal, but safe enough in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

I would disable editing on the parent feature layer which will have point/line/polygon geometry in the web map while the related records in the table are still editable and not impacted by this. This keeps the parent locked in a un-editbale form in the map while the related records can be edited.

Comment: This was my initial thought, but if I do that I cannot edit any of the attributes in the parent feature layer.  And because you cannot symbolize based on what is in the related table I need to maintain an inspection complete (yes/no) field in the parent feature that will be edited to display what has and has not been inspected.  Unless there is another way to do this.

Comment: are the field users updating the parent feature or are you? Also this would become an issue if you are using a 1-M for inspections or would you create a new feature layer for each round of inspections and keep it 1-1? Maybe this blog post can help you out https://www.prowestgis.com/update-on-symbolizing-features-by-related-record-values-in-arcgis/

Comment: The field users will be updating the parent feature, but only one of the fields.  I am using a 1-M relationship because I don't want to create a new feature layer for each round of inspections, that is also why the field in the parent feature needs to be updated, is so that new table records can be created for each set of inspections.