# Related Tables can be viewed in my webmap but not in Collector

Tags: arcgis-10.3, arcgis-online, relationship-class, relates, arcgis-collector

I have a related table set up in an ArcGIS webmap. I can view the related data (1:M) just fine in the webmap. However, when I try to view the related data in Collector, there is nothing there. Is there a setting I did not set up correctly? Have others faced this problem?

**Here are my current settings**:

- The layer with the related table is editable.
- The popup for the related table is configured and enabled.
- 'Filter Related Types' under Collections Options on the Collector app is off.
- The related data was set up using the Create Relationship Class on Desktop and then published.
- There are no filters in place nor is visibility limited for the layer.
- The Collector app is 'connected' However, it the app should be functional in 'disconnected' mode.

I have an almost identical webmap & Collector app for a separate geographic area working just fine.

Comment: When you shared map as service, was related table added to mxd?

Comment: The table was existing in the mxd before publishing. The hosted service, with the table, was added to the webmap. Hopefully I answered your question.

Comment: Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213867/creating-a-collector-map-that-allows-new-records-to-be-added-to-a-related-table could be something to do with editing enabled

Answer (score 2):

After walking back my steps, I found that the relationship class set up in the MXD had the Origin Table & Destination Table flipped. I created a new relationship class, republished the service and now all is well.

[image]